# How to Use CURL to call APIs

Tags: php, api, curl

i am using PHP to send a message using text api.  using the following CURL piece of code.

```
 $curl_handle=curl_init();
 $url="";//url will be populated here
 curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
 $resultcode = curl_exec($curl_handle);
 print($resultcode);
 curl_close($curl_handle);
```

Issue is,  when ever i submit a request text API receives my computer IP address as sender, but actually it should the dedicated server IP which domain is hosted.

Can you please help me to find the code where i can submit the request so reciever takes server ip address

Update:

Text API system needs to be whitelist the IPs where the request comes in, i have given the dedicated server ip.   but when ever i submit the request Text API system blocks my requests because they are receiving from different IP. it means its taking my computer IP and not the IP address of the website.  little messy thing but hope you guys give me a better clarify on this.

Thank you,

Comment: Where exactly are you running curl? You can't put in your local PC's ip address and expect the response to look as if it came from some other server - that sort of TCP spoofing is not possible without total control of the network infrastructure between you and the API's server.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely look over this page to familiarize yourself with all of the possible set-up options for cURL:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

That said, scroll down to "Force Curl Request To Go To A Particular IP Address"

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible to "spoof" the IP address from which a request originated, it is not trivial - which is why originating IP address is used for identification and security, which is presumably what you're experiencing.

The bottom line is, the API will always see the external address of whatever computer you run this code on.